# How can we get new upload data on another website in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

i am develop web software in asp.net MVC .. i want get information that are given on different websites like email addresses  that are different companies email address ... then help me how can i get information that newly upload on different sites..

Comment: have you ever tried webrequest to get the another website content. And then you can use HtmlAgilityPack to extract the content you want from whole web page content

Comment: can you share me code for that webrequest?

Answer (score 0):

Just consider you want to get data from www.example.com. First you have to read whole html on this site as a string, then you have to filter out the details you want. You can use webclient, as it is easy to use.

Following code may help you.

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string result = client.DownloadString("http://www.example.com");   
}
```

Now you have whole html as string. You can filter out from this string.

```
private void GetEmails(string result)
{
    //regular expression 
    string pattern = @"(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@" + @"((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\." + @"([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|"+ @"([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})";

    //Set up regex object 
    Regex RegExpr = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    //get the first match 
    Match match = RegExpr.Match(content);

    //loop through matches 
    while (match.Success)
    {
        //here you got the email.
        string email = match.Groups[0].Value;

        //get next match 
        match = match.NextMatch();
    }
}
```

Comment: in this code what is "content"..how can i set the content value?

Comment: "content" is "result" coming as an argument in the function. It is set in first block of the code.